# Retrieving a child returns null snapshot

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two child nodes setup in my firebase database and I can view both of these in the firebase database viewer. Both these child nodes are at the root level. When I access the child nodes using this piece of code:

```
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {...}
```

the child labelled "USd2016d04d24" returns the correct JSON data. However, when I access the child labelled "USd2016d04d25", the snapshot is returned as null. As you can see from this[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgCWv.jpg), there is valid data saved within the latter node. I can't figure out why would there be a discrepancy in reading the data from two similar nodes. Any pointers?

Comment: Without seeing a [minimal-but-complete piece of code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be hard to help. I also note that you've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on what is meant by 'access the child labelled xxxxx'. Do you have some code that shows how you access the child data?